# How to prevent .jar files from going into /etc when installing OpenJDK from rpm?

Tags: fedora, package-management, yum, java

After I found and installed OpenJDK in Fedora 20 using Apper I noticed there is a series of directories starting with `jar` prefix under `/etc/alternatives`, specifically:

```
/etc/alternatives/jre (93,4MB)
/etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0 (93,4MB)
/etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0_exports (1,3GB)
/etc/alternatives/jre_exports (1,3GB)
/etc/alternatives/jre_openjdk (93,4MB)
/etc/alternatives/jre_openjdk_exports (1,3GB)
```

with total size of **4,3GB**

Can I direct Apper/yum/whatever to put these files in some other location as I keep my whole `/etc` directory in Dropbox and I do not want to have these gigantic jar files there.
Also, I do not think this type of files belong to `/etc` at all which makes me wonder why they were put there in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These `.jar` files are not really being installed into the `/etc` directory. There's a software package called `alternatives` which maintains a set of Unix links which allows a system to have multiple versions of tools with the same name. In this case those names would be the executables that are included with Java. The multiple versions would be typically Oracle's JDK and the OpenJDK project's.

You can use the command line tool `readlink` to see where these exectuables are actually residing on disk.

```
$ readlink -f /etc/alternatives/jre
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.4.1.fc19.x86_64/jre
```

`alternatives` also can maintain executables that live in `/usr/bin` too.

```
$ type jar
jar is /usr/bin/jar
$ readlink -f /usr/bin/jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.4.1.fc19.x86_64/bin/jar

$ type java
java is /usr/bin/java
$ readlink -f /usr/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.4.1.fc19.x86_64/jre/bin/java
```

You can read more about the `alternatives` command via its [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/alternatives). This tutorial titled: [Install Oracle Java JDK/JRE 7u51 on Fedora 20/19, CentOS/RHEL 6.5/5.10](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-sun-oracle-java-jdk-jre-7-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/) shows the `alternatives` command in action too.

Comment: Thanks. Do you personally think *alternatives* does the right thing by putting these links in `/etc` directory?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost - Sure I've been using `alternatives` for years now to manage multi installs of Java. It works fine.

Comment: I do not question that it works fine :) I'm concerned with the place (`/etc`) which it chose to keep these links. I believe `/etc` is meant for configuration and not for keeping *random* links. Wouldn't something like `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` be a better place?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost - sorry my comment was meant towards that part of your Q. No these links are technically configuration, that's why they're maintained in `/etc.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost The links themselves are configuration, not their target. Configure Dropbox to synchronize the link as such (if it can), or to skip `/etc/alternatives`.